# .NET Core Reflection - How to find references of a property inside ASP.NET Core 3 Razor Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reflection, system.reflection

I have Razor Views with [localizated resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) using IViewLocalizer like this:

```html
@inject  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer Localizer
...
@Localizer.GetString("Click here to Log in")
```

**I'm trying to extract all those strings from my precompiled views** (to build a PO file dictionary), so I think I'll have to **find all references of IViewLocalizer injected into my views**, something like this:

```cs
var findAll = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                         BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile("MySite.Web.Views.dll"));
var view = asm.GetType("AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index");
var props = view.GetProperties(findAll).Where(p=>p.PropertyType.FullName == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer").ToList();

// I want to find all references that use this this IViewLocalizer Localizer.get()
var getter = props.First().GetGetMethod().MetadataToken; 

// How can I do it?
var allMethods = view.GetMethods(findAll);
foreach(var method in allMethods)
{
    // How can I check my methods for usages of that property getter, and in case get the strings?
}
```

I tried using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034906/3606250) which uses MethodBase.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray() but it didn't work - looks like the method `public override Task ExecuteAsync()` is very short, so it looks like my view is rendered somewhere else.

And additionally, I'm not sure if I should look for the MetadataToken of the getter (IViewLocalizer injected into my views) or if I should look for usages of any concrete method which implements `IViewLocalizer.GetString(string)` and `IViewLocalizer.GetString(string, params object[])` .

PS: I'm aware that I can use Regex over my cshtml views, as long as the injected localizer follows some naming standard. That's Plan B in case I can't figure out the reflection solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of ILSpy (and later confirmed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29181749/3606250) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29180558/3606250)) I've discovered that **async methods (as well as iterator classes) are generated across nested helper classes that represent the state machine**. These helper classes can be found in the NestedTypes property of the main type.

I could find multiple calls to the method which I was looking for (getter of my IViewLocalizer) when I added to my search all methods in inner types. **This worked:**

```cs
var allMethods = view.GetMethods(findAll).ToList();
allMethods.AddRange( // also search in methods of nested types
  view.GetNestedTypes(findAll).SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods(findAll)));

foreach(var method in allMethods)
{
    var usages = ((MethodBase)method).GetMethodUsageOffsets(get);
    if (usages.Count() > 0)
        Debug.WriteLine($"{method.ReflectedType.FullName}.{method.Name}");
}
```

**All calls which I was expecting to find in AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3.ExecuteAsync() were actually spread over these methods in inner types:**

```
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<ExecuteAsync>d__22.MoveNext
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<<ExecuteAsync>b__22_0>d.MoveNext
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<<ExecuteAsync>b__22_1>d.MoveNext
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<<ExecuteAsync>b__22_2>d.MoveNext
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<<ExecuteAsync>b__22_3>d.MoveNext
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<<ExecuteAsync>b__22_4>d.MoveNext
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<<ExecuteAsync>b__22_5>d.MoveNext
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index3+<<ExecuteAsync>b__22_6>d.MoveNext
... etc... all states from the state machine
```

Using Mono.Cecil it became even easier since I don't even need this `GetMethodUsageOffsets` [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034906/3606250), since Cecil can interpret bytecodes easily:

```cs
var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(System.IO.Path.Combine(appFolder, "MyApp.Web.Views.dll"));
var type = module.Types.First(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Index3"));
var allInstructions = typeDefinition.Methods
    .Union(typeDefinition.NestedTypes.SelectMany(x => x.Methods))
    .Where(m => m.HasBody)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Body.Instructions).ToList();

var calls = allInstructions.Where(i => i.ToString().Contains(
                "callvirt Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.LocalizedString Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IHtmlLocalizer::GetString(System.String)")).ToList();

foreach (var call in calls) // previous is where string parameter is loaded
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.Previous.ToString());
```

**Results:**

```
IL_020a: ldstr "More Options"
IL_0241: ldstr "Add Text"
IL_15c8: ldstr "Reset"
IL_15ff: ldstr "Save Text Box Settings"
IL_0019: ldstr "None"
...etc
```

**Edit of 2020-09-23**:
I've just discovered that some methods can be split into multiple levels, so searching only for first-level NestedTypes doesn't work. Since I'm currently using Cecil (instead of pure reflection), this is my current code:

```cs
// All assemblies that I want to scan
var modules = new List<ModuleDefinition>();
modules.Add(ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(System.IO.Path.Combine(appFolder, "MyProject.Web.Views.dll")));
modules.Add(ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(System.IO.Path.Combine(appFolder, "MyProject.Web.dll")));

// All types in my Assemblies
var allTypes = modules.SelectMany(m => m.Types).ToList();

// Then for each of those types I get all Nested Types:

// Get all nested types
for(int i = 0; I < allTypes.Count(); i++) 
    allTypes.AddRange(allTypes[i].NestedTypes); 

// Get all instructions using Cecil
var allInstructions = allTypes.SelectMany(x => x.Methods)
    .Where(m => m.HasBody)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Body.Instructions).ToList();

var i18nInstructions = allInstructions.Where(i => 
    i.ToString().Contains("GetString(System.String)") 
    || i.ToString().Contains("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.HtmlLocalizerExtensions::GetHtml(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IHtmlLocalizer,System.String)")
    ).ToList();

// This prints all values of "ldstr 'value'" 
// which happen before GetString() or GetHtml()
foreach (var i in i18nInstructions)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.Previous.Operand.ToString());
```